# How do SVG path rendering algorithms ensure that areas are not painted twice?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, rasterizing

I was reading about path rasterization algorithms, trying to figure out how the intersecting parts in a SVG path are not drawn twice.

Looking at the image below of a self intersecting path which was drawn translucent `rgba(0,0,228,78)`, we can see that the color stays consistent on the intersecting part. Are SVG paths usually drawn off-screen and then later applied on the canvas with the specified colors?

[image: overlapping path]

Comment: SVG is no different to canvas or any other web technology. The underlying graphics engines on the operating system handles this sort of thing basically.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, I am interested in how the graphics engine would do that

Comment: On what operating system? This is an operating system graphics engine question, not an SVG question then.

Comment: Roughly: find intersections of the shape, turn into outline, fill that outline w/ the appropriate color/transparency/etc. It's more likely you're looking for a book on computer graphics--the precise method(s) are longer than a trivial SO answer.

Comment: @DaveNewton Do you have a book recommendation?

Comment: @Julius Nope, no clue what a good graphics book is these days. You could try on the [Computer Graphics (Beta) Stack Exchange](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This becomes easy to understand if instead of moving along the shape and drawing pixels you instead move through every pixel and ask wether it is inside the shape. since you only ask this question once for each pixel it is ever only drawn once.